# Sum of occurrence - measure - power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the dataset:

[image]

I've checked the occurrence of each id and if it was the first occurrence per the id, I assigned the value 0, otherwise 1.

[image]

If I create a pivot table and sum of occurrence, I will get :

[image]

So, my final desired outcome is:

[image]

I can achieve it with the countrows and sum of countrows as a calculated column but it is static and as soon as I start using the date filter, the formula doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve it with a measure?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create these below 2 **Measures**-

**Note:** Considered ordering using column **ticket_id**

```
occ = 

VAR current_ticket_id = MIN(your_table_name[ticket_id])
VAR current_id = MIN(your_table_name[id])

VAR count_id = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(your_table_name),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[id] = current_id
        && your_table_name[ticket_id] <= current_ticket_id
    )
)

RETURN 
IF(
    count_id = 1,
    0,
    1
)
```

```
sum of occ = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(your_table_name),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[id]),
        [occ] = 1
    )
) + 0
```

Here is the output-

[image]

Comment: R_R, it is great and works when NO filters applied but remember that in the first place, the problem was created because if I started using the date when the ticket was created as a filter, my calculated col formula stops working. The same is with your formula, it works well when no filter applied but doesn't work when I select different date range, for example.

Comment: Filter on which column?

Comment: My fault, didn't include it to the dataset. I've updated the main question. On top of it, potentially, there will be other columns that could be used as filters along with the 'created date'.

Comment: Filtering by Year? Or month? Or date? Can you explain?

Comment: As a filter in the filter pane - I've added the screenshot to the main question.

Comment: Shall I change all to allexcept and add all my filter columns there?

Comment: Yes, you already got my point. ALLEXCEPT should work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223669/discussion-between-r-r-and-eponkratova).